# Using dsfont package in R Markdown via R Studio

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

So I can't for the life of me including this dsfont package in R Markdown. I really want to use the double-stroke letters.

I include it in the header like so:

```
header-includes:
- \usepackage{dsfont}
```

And I use $\mathds{P}$, for example to denote probability.

The file knit fine with no error but the HTML output is \mathdsP, i.e. it doesn't work.

I tried downloading the dsfont zip directly from CTAN but when I click download nothing happens.

What do I need to do to make this work?

Comment: You are knitting to HTML where as `\usepackage` is a LaTeX command used for PDF outputs.

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to include additional LaTeX packages for HTML output?

Comment: I do not see any way to use `dsfont` with MathJax (LaTeX renderer for HTML).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\usepackage` is a command for PDF output.
It is not possible to use `dsfont` with HTML output.